Creating a git branch from just before a specific commit
I'm confused by the instructions here that say
Create the release branch starting just before your commit and push it to GitHub:
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b v$MAJOR.$MINOR.x \
  $(git log --pretty=format:%H --grep "^Start $MAJOR.$((MINOR+1)).0 development cycle$" upstream/master)^

From what I read from other documentation however, this command is for creating a branch from the specified commit, not from just before that commit, so I don't understand why the first reference I mentioned thinks the command will start the branch omitting that commit. Can someone please clarify?

The ^ at the very end goes up a commit.

Or tilda (~).
